# Fillable forms: two filled in copies of same form, 2nd one doesn't print data

Tags: itext

All,
I have two PDFs.  They are the same PDF, but filled in with different information. For instance, the Company field will have "ABC Company" as the filled in data for PDF1 and "XYZ Company" as the filled in data for PDF 2.
When merging, I will get both documents, but the 2nd one will contain no data in the fillable fields.
I can switch the order they get merged and always the first one will have data, but the 2nd one will have no data.
From researching, it seems as if there might be issues due to the fields on the pages all having the same name?  Could this be the issue?

I am using version:  iText 5.4

Thanks for any help/suggestions you can provide.

--- 9/10/2018 Code to show.
FYI. I have taken over this code from someone who wrote it years ago and have not worked with Itext before so I am just digging in.  Here is the code that I am using. Oracle calling Java to run the code.

### As always, thanks for the responses that already came in and any future ones..thx.

```
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;

public class PdfMerger {
    public static void merge(ResultSet pdfs, Blob dest) throws Exception {
        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, dest.setBinaryStream(0));
        doc.open();
        while (pdfs.next()) {
            PdfReader rdr = new PdfReader(pdfs.getBinaryStream(1));
            for (int i = 1; i <= rdr.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
                copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(rdr, i));
        }
        copy.close();
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

---

--JM

Thanks for the response about :

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.close();
```

As a non Java person, (strictly PL/SQL) I very much appreciate the assistance.  Where would these three lines be placed in the code above to flatten the docs?
I apologize for not knowing more, but I just got placed on this project.  Appreciate the help. This is the last step to completion and if I could get over this hurdle....

Would it look like?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "PdfMergerTest" as import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

public class PdfMergerTest {
    public static void merge(ResultSet pdfs, Blob dest) throws Exception {
        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, dest.setBinaryStream(0));
        doc.open();
        while (pdfs.next()) {
            PdfReader rdr = new PdfReader(pdfs.getBinaryStream(1));
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(rdr,copy);
            stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
            stamper.close();            
            for (int i = 1; i <= rdr.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
                copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(rdr, i));
        }
        copy.close();
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show how you merge the files. There are appropriate and inappropriate ways to do so if firms are involved.

Comment: *`PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(rdr,copy)`* - There is no `PdfStamper` constructor that accepts a `PdfCopy` as second (i.e. output) parameter. Use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead. After closing the stamper you can retrieve the bytes from that output stream and initialize a new `PdfReader` with them. Then import from that new reader.

Answer (score 1):

You should flatten PDF forms before merging/joining:

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.close();
```

Field values will then become part of the document as a text instead of *field + value* and it will prevent collision between field values of merged documents.

**Update:** The result code in your case will be:

```
PdfReader rdr = new PdfReader(pdfs.getBinaryStream(1));
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(rdr, output);
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.close();            

rdr = new PdfReader(output.toByteArray());
for (int i = 1; i <= rdr.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(rdr, i));
}
```

It means that it fills form using `PdfStamper` and saves it into the `ByteArraouOutputStream` and then it again reads the filled PDF and adds page by page into the `PdfCopy`.

You can also try to use `PdfSmartCopy` instead of `PdfCopy` to reduce the PDF file size. `PdfSmartCopy` tries to share the same objects across the result joined PDF, but it needs much more memory then `PdfCopy` and will be slower.

Comment: That's appropriate *unless the op needs the result to still be a form*.

Comment: @JimMiller I updated the answer with exact code for you.